# SwiftUI Button Background Exceeds Size of Button

Tags: xcode, button, swiftui

I have the following code below which has two buttons. For some reason when the right one has a background set it to it, it exceeds the size of the button. This only happens when it is near the bottom of the screen (removing the spacer between the VStack and HStack solves this problem. Does anyone know why it's happening?

```
struct LoginRegister: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("photo")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button("LOG IN") {
                    print("Log in Pressed")
                }
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 40)
                .border(.black, width: 2, cornerRadius: 5)
                
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 20)
                
                Button("REGISTER") {
                    print("Register Pressed")
                }
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 40)
                .background(.black)
                .border(.black, width: 2, cornerRadius: 5)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func border(_ color: Color, width: CGFloat, cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> some View {
        overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius).stroke(color, lineWidth: width))
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it is happening, but to fix the problem try this: `.background(.black).clipped()` or `HStack {...}.clipped()`

Comment: Thank you @workingdog that does work. Might be a bug in SwiftUI

Comment: even works on the outer `VStack{...}.clipped()`